# Filling a char pointer in a struct

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, char

I have defined a "car" struct with a model (char *model) and the year of the model (int year).  I have a function that will create a new car struct; however, it is seg faulting when copying the char pointers.  This is supposed to create a new node for a linked list.

```
Car *newCar(char *model, int year){
    Car *new = malloc(sizeof(Car));
    new->year = year;
    new->model = malloc(MAX_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(new->model, model);
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}
```

Comment: How about `new->model = malloc(strlen(model) + 1)` ?

Comment: You should check that `char *model` is not `NULL`. Also, as good practice, always check the return of `malloc`s.

Comment: @cnicutar thanks; however, the issues is still there.

Comment: @Cong Xu char *model will never be NULL because it is scanning in data from a file in another function.

Comment: first of all dont use new as variable name as it is a keyword

Comment: @KinjalPatel , he can safely use new with a c compiler

Comment: r u sure that char *model is NULL terminated?

Comment: have you tried what cnicutar has proposed.....that is new->model = malloc(strlen(model) + 1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For future reference this function fixed my issue...

```
Car *createCar(char *model, int year){
    Car *new = malloc(sizeof(Car));
    new->year = year;
    new->model = malloc(strlen(model)+1);
    strcpy(new->model, model);
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}
```

Comment: You malloc'd the wrong amount of space. It should be `strlen(model)+1`.  If this appeared to fix your issue, you have been walking on eggshells!

Comment: @M.M you're right! I was going through my old homework assignments from freshman year and realized that I never posted the solution.  I've updated my answer to reflect the error you caught.

Answer (score 4):

Here your model is character pointer.

But strcpy requires two arguments - that should be `array` or `character pointer to which memory allocated by malloc or calloc`

But your `strcpy();` takes one argument as character pointer which will not be accepted.

so make

`new->model = malloc(strlen(model) + 1)` and then write your `strcpy
()` it will work.

Comment: or `new->model = strdup (model);` which does the same in one single instruction.

Comment: @EdouardThiel Except `strdup` isn't standard (although it can easily be implemented).

Comment: strdup() conforms to SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this :

```
new->model = model == NULL ? NULL : strdup(model);
```

this prevents you from a bug if model is NULL, else malloc you the exact amount of space and strcopy it; plus, this allows you to `free(new->model)` at the end in all the cases.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the code below and compare it with your program, am sure you will find out what's wrong with your program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct car{
char *model;
int year;
}Car;

Car * newCar(char *, int );

int main()
{

Car *benz = newCar("S-class",1990);

printf("\nModel = %s\n",benz->model);
printf("\nYear = %d\n",benz->year);

}

Car * newCar(char *model, int year)
{
    Car *new = malloc(sizeof(Car));
    new->year = year;
    new->model = malloc(strlen(model));
    strcpy(new->model, model);
    return new;
}
```